# My web app server sends emails. I also use Google Apps to host my emails. I can't send messages to my own users?

Tags: sendmail, exim4

Please excuse the horrible title. I've been banging my head against this issue all afternoon, only to realize that I was on a wild goose chase.

In short:

- Set up Google Apps to handle incoming emails for my domain (`foobar.org`)
- Set up exim4 on my Linode to send outgoing emails for my web app
- Tested by sending emails to my private email (`julian@otherdomain.net`), and to work email (`julian@foobar.org`).

After 3 hours,  I still could not figure out why emails were being received at `otherdomain.net`, but not at `foobar.org`.

So I gave up. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>** out of the super-user account, and saw: `You have new mail in /var/mail/julian`

*facepalm*

---

So, any outgoing emails sent to `foobar.org` get delivered to the local user account. Makes sense. How do I tell `exim4` to send the email out to the interwebs, so when it comes back to my DNS, it'll be routed to Google's servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had an incorrect hosts file entry added when setting up my server.

I had the following entry:

```
public-ip    domain.tld    machinename
```

Although the following was more appropriate

```
public-ip    machinename.domain.tld    machinename
```

From then on, all emails sent to `domain.tld` ended up being sent out of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your local mail service needs to be set up to use the MX record for your domain. Using things like Plesk or Cpanel it's a case of shutting down the email service and ensuring the local DNS records included an A record for the external mail exchanger (Google) and a suitable MX record pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

https://serverfault.com/a/341779/80240